# My datareader has row(s), but I am failing to get the record(s) to textbox from datareader

Tags: asp.net

can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong.I am trying to develop a small site on my own using c#.I am unable to show the record which was fetched from datareader.

```
{

    SqlConnection cone = new SqlConnection("User id=...;Password=;...");

    SqlCommand conecmd = new SqlCommand("select bankbalance from bank where bankpassword='" + txtboxbankpassword.Text + "'", cone);

    cone.Open();

    SqlDataReader drcone = conecmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (drcone.HasRows) // says it has row(s) i.e., Hasrows=true
    {

        while (drcone.Read()) // here its value is false
        {
            lblremainingbankbalance.Text = drcone["bankbalance"].ToString();
        }
        int a;
        a = Convert.ToInt32(lblremainingbankbalance.Text);


        lblmsg.Text = "Transaction successful.Please wait while we redirect you to mypage and your current " + bankstore + " accountbalance is " + a + "";
        Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "5;URL=Mypage.aspx");
        txtboxbankpassword.Text = "";
    } else {
        lblmsg.Text = "Norecord(s)";
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean it doesn't come in while loop ?

Comment: Hi Mairaj, yes it did not come in while loop.

Comment: Maybe I am shooting at the air but... If you are using the debugger to inspect drcone maybe one Read has been executed and when you reach while you are at the end of the steam.

Comment: jlvaquero, that means, how to get the records from datareader then ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your query in SQL server and see if it shows some rows because i don't see any errors in code also trim the text of your textbox like this

```
  txtboxbankpassword.Text.Trim()
```

Also close you connection when you are done with reading rows from datareader.

Comment: Yes,the query works correct in SQL server.I also trim the text.

Comment: then debug your code and check one thing that you are setting value in loop if there is last row which has empty value.

Answer (score 0):

your case is very strange.. if `drcone.HasRows`is true `drcone.Read()` have to return true... minimum for one time..

Are you debugging the code and add `drcone.Read()` to quickwatch or have it in your watchlist? Because, then it will run the method `Read()` before your while loop. Next time when you call `Read()` (in your while-loop) it will return false..

You get one row, the reader aligns the reader to the first row (in whatchlist), and returns false in your while loop and saying "there are no rows left after this one".

See this link Here for the documentation on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx

if you have only a singlerow, the reader "is on position -1".. after drcone.Read() (return true) set the position to 0 (1 and last row).. next time you call drcone.Read() it will return false.. because there are no rows left after this one (reader is on position 0)

Comment: Edi G, I got it.I did as :  drcone.Read();
                      if (drcone.HasRows)
                      {
                      lblremainingbankbalance.Text = drcone.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                     // remaining code}